# Rotating Text in Circular Pattern Using JavaFX

Tags: java, java-8, javafx

Just wanted to see what you all thought about my program, I basically have two different classes that I designed to allow for automated wrapping of text in a circular pattern. This is my first bit of useful and reusable code. Let me know what can be improved or added.

Here are some screenshots I took of the program in action:

[image] [image]

Below is the main part of the program to let you see how it is used within the program:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/17/2014.
 */
public class MouseEventDemo extends Application {
    public double rotateImage;
    Pane pane = new Pane();

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Set pane's properties
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");

        // Create and add objects
        setMouseTrail();
        setCenterObject();

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("MouseTrailDemo"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    /** Set mouse trail */
    public void setMouseTrail() {
        // Create image for cursor
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("/image/anon5.jpg"));
        imageView.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SCREEN);
        imageView.setCache(true);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

        // Create a new RotatingText object
        Font font = Font.font("Courier New", FontWeight.BOLD, 12);
        RotatingText circlePane = new RotatingText("We Are Anonymous",
                220, font);
        circlePane.setCircleSize(36);
        circlePane.setTextColor(Color.LIME);
        circlePane.relocate(imageView.getX(), imageView.getY());
        pane.getChildren().add(circlePane);

        // Rotation transform for animation counter clockwise
        final Rotate rotationTransform = new Rotate(360, 0, 0);
        circlePane.getTransforms().add(rotationTransform);

        // Animate the RotatingText object
        Timeline rotatingText = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(5),
                new KeyValue(rotationTransform.angleProperty(), 0)));
        rotatingText.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rotatingText.play();

        // Set text to circle image and image to follow mouse
        pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            imageView.setX(e.getX() - 10);
            imageView.setY(e.getY() + 30);
            circlePane.relocate(imageView.getX() + 34,
                    imageView.getY() + 29.5);
        });
    }

    /** Set center object and animate it */
    public void setCenterObject() {
        // Create circular text
        Font font2 = Font.font("Courier New", FontWeight.BOLD, 12);
        CircularText circularText = new CircularText("We Are Anonymous",
                325, 325);
        circularText.setTextFill(Color.LIME);
        circularText.setTextSize(12, 1.3, 1.1);
        circularText.setFont(font2);
        circularText.setTextRotate(90, 360);
        circularText.setGapSpacing(0.95);
        circularText.setTextStartDegree(360);
        circularText.relocate(300, 300);
        pane.getChildren().add(circularText);

        // Rotation transform for circular text animation and image
        final Rotate rotationTransform = new Rotate(360, 0, 0);
        circularText.getTransforms().add(rotationTransform);


        // Animate the RotatingText object
        Timeline rotatingText = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(10),
                new KeyValue(rotationTransform.angleProperty(), 0)));
        rotatingText.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rotatingText.play();

        // Load image for center
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(new Image("/image/anon3.jpg"));
        imageView2.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SCREEN);
        imageView2.setCache(true);
        imageView2.setX(circularText.getLayoutX() - 145);
        imageView2.setY(circularText.getLayoutY() - 125);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);

        // Create EventHandler for image
        rotateImage = 0;
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e -> {
            if (rotateImage == 360)
                rotateImage = 0;
            rotateImage += 1;
            imageView2.setRotate(rotateImage);
        };

        // Animate the image rotation
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(35), eventHandler));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

Here is the `RotatingText` class that controls the text rotating around the mouse trail:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/19/2014.
 */
public class RotatingText extends Pane {
    private double circleSize;
    private double textRotate;
    private String phrase;
    private double startDegree;
    private double letterSpacing;
    private double pointX;
    private double pointY;
    private double rotate;

    // Objects and properties
    ArrayList<String> phraseList;
    private Text text;
    private Font textFont;
    private Color textColor;

    /** Default Constructor */
    public RotatingText() {
        this.circleSize = 100;
        this.textFont = new Font("Courier New", 15);
        this.phrase = "Default";
        this.startDegree = 220;
        this.letterSpacing = 21;
        this.textRotate = 100;
        this.textColor = Color.BLACK;
        paintText(this.phrase);
    }

    /** Constructor for setting phrase, starting degree, and the font */
    public RotatingText(String phrase, double startDegree, Font font) {
        this.circleSize = 100;
        this.textFont = font;
        this.textRotate = 90;
        this.textColor = Color.BLACK;
        this.phrase = phrase;
        this.startDegree = startDegree;
        this.letterSpacing = 21;
        paintText(this.phrase);
    }

    /** Get the color of Font */
    public Color getTextColor() {
        return this.textColor;
    }

    /** Set the color of Font */
    public void setTextColor(Color color) {
        this.textColor = color;
        paintText(this.phrase);
    }

    /** Get the Font */
    public Font getTextFont() {
        return this.textFont;
    }

    /** Set the Font */
    public void setTextFont(Font font) {
        this.textFont = font;
        paintText(this.phrase);
    }

    /** Get the size of the circle */
    public double getCircleSize() {
        return this.circleSize;
    }

    /** Set the size of the circle */
    public void setCircleSize(double circleSize) {
        this.circleSize = circleSize;
        paintText(this.phrase);
    }

    /** Get the rotation setting of the text */
    public double getTextRotate() {
        return this.textRotate;
    }

    /** Set the rotation setting of the text */
    public void setTextRotate(double textRotate) {
        this.textRotate = textRotate;
        paintText(this.phrase);
    }

    /** Get the spacing between letters */
    public double getLetterSpacing() {
        return this.letterSpacing;
    }

    /** Set the spacing between letters */
    public void setLetterSpacing(double letterSpacing) {
        this.letterSpacing = letterSpacing;
        paintText(this.phrase);
    }

    /** Paint's the text in a circular fashion */
    private void paintText(String phrase) {
        getChildren().clear();
        // Create ArrayList and store each letter as a string
        this.phraseList = new ArrayList<>(phrase.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            phraseList.add(i, String.valueOf(phrase.charAt(i)));
        }

        // Create letters and place them around the circle
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            addLetter(this.textFont, this.textColor,
                    phraseList.get(i), startDegree);
            getChildren().add(this.text);
            startDegree += letterSpacing;
        }
    }

    /** Create letter and add it to pane */
    public void addLetter(Font font, Color color, String letter,
                          double startDegree) {
        getCoordinates(startDegree);
        text = new Text(this.pointX, this.pointY, letter);
        text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setFill(color);
        text.setRotate(this.rotate);
    }

    /** Sets letter coordinates based on degree */
    public void getCoordinates(double degree) {
        this.pointX = (this.getWidth() / 2) + circleSize *
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree));
        this.pointY = (this.getHeight() / 2) + circleSize *
                Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree));
        this.pointX -= (this.textFont.getSize() / 3);
        this.pointY += (this.textFont.getSize() / 3);
        this.rotate = degree + this.textRotate;
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the code for the `Circular Text` class which rotates around the center object and yes I know you are thinking, what's the point in having two? Well this one was my original and I decided to try and simplify it, that and I just learned how to animate things so I didn't realize there was a simpler way to rotate text and therefore I was trying to setup the ability to have an `EventHandler` redraw the text and in case you was wondering.  That's why I probably forgot to remove the `getChildren.clear()`.  The one below was the first one I wrote and the one above is the second, revised version.

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/11/2014.
 */
public class CircularText extends Pane {
    private double circleWidth;
    private double circleHeight;
    private double textSize;
    private double textStartDegree;
    private double letterPos;
    private double textRotate;
    private double gapSpacing;
    private double offSetX;
    private double offSetY;
    private Font font;
    private Paint textFill;
    private String fontName;
    final String text;

    /** Default Constructor */
    public CircularText(String text) {
        this.circleWidth = 250;
        this.circleHeight = 250;
        this.text = text;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / this.text.length()) * 2;
        this.fontName = "Courier New";
        this.font = new Font(this.fontName, textSize);
        this.textFill = Color.BLACK;
        this.textStartDegree = 240;
        this.gapSpacing = 0.975;
        this.letterPos = 360 / (text.length() / this.gapSpacing);
        this.textRotate = 90;
        this.offSetX = 4;
        this.offSetY = 3;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Create Constructor */
    public CircularText (String text, double width, double height) {
        this.circleWidth = width;
        this.circleHeight = height;
        this.text = text;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / (this.text.length()) * 2);
        this.fontName = "Courier New";
        this.font = new Font(this.fontName, textSize);
        this.textFill = Color.BLACK;
        this.textStartDegree = 240;
        this.gapSpacing = 0.975;
        this.letterPos = 360 / (text.length() / this.gapSpacing);
        this.textRotate = 90;
        this.offSetX = 4;
        this.offSetY = 3;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get font color */
    public Paint getTextFill() {
        return textFill;
    }

    /** Set font color */
    public void setTextFill(Paint textFill) {
        this.textFill = textFill;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get starting position for text */
    public double getTextStartDegree() {
        return textStartDegree;
    }

    /** Set starting position for text */
    public void setTextStartDegree(double textStartDegree) {
        this.textStartDegree = textStartDegree;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get the placement in degrees of each letter */
    public double getLetterPos() {
        return this.letterPos;
    }

    /** Set the placement in degrees of each letter */
    public void setLetterPos(double degrees) {
        this.letterPos = degrees / (text.length() / this.gapSpacing);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get letter rotation */
    public double getTextRotate() {
        return textRotate;
    }

    /** Set letter rotation */
    public void setTextRotate(double textRotate, double textFlowControl) {
        this.textRotate = textRotate;
        setLetterPos(textFlowControl);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get spacing between ending and beginning of phrase */
    public double getGapSpacing() {
        return gapSpacing;
    }

    /** Set spacing between ending and beginning of phrase */
    public void setGapSpacing(double gapSpacing) {
        this.gapSpacing = gapSpacing;
        this.letterPos = 360 / (text.length() / this.gapSpacing);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get current font */
    public Font getFont() {
        return this.font;
    }

    /** Set new font */
    public void setFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Set new font name */
    public void setFont(String name) {
        this.fontName = name;
        this.font = new Font(this.fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Set font name, text size, offSetX, and offSetY */
    public void setFont(String name, double textSize,
                        double offSetX, double offSetY) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.offSetX = offSetX;
        this.offSetY = offSetY;
        this.fontName = name;
        this.font = new Font(this.fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Return textSize */
    public double getTextSize() {
        return this.textSize;
    }

    /** Set textSize */
    public void setTextSize(double textSize, double offSetX,
                            double offSetY) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.offSetX = offSetX;
        this.offSetY = offSetY;
        this.font = new Font(this.fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Return circle's width */
    public double getCircleWidth() {
        return circleWidth;
    }

    /** Set circle's width */
    public void setCircleWidth(double w) {
        this.circleWidth = w;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / this.text.length()) * 2;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Return circle's height */
    public double getCircleHeight() {
        return circleHeight;
    }

    /** Set circle's height */
    public void setCircleHeight(double h) {
        this.circleHeight = h;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / this.text.length()) * 2;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Paint the Letters */
    protected void paintText(String text, Font font) {
        getChildren().clear();
        // Initialize parameters
        double radius = Math.min(circleWidth, circleHeight) * 0.8 * 0.5;
        double centerX = this.getWidth() / 2;
        double centerY = this.getHeight() / 2;

        // Place text in a circular pattern
        int i = 0;
        double degree = this.letterPos;
        for (double degrees = this.textStartDegree;
             i < text.length(); i++, degrees += degree) {
            double pointX = centerX + radius *
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
            double pointY = centerY + radius *
                Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees));
            pointX -= (font.getSize() / 3);
            pointY += (font.getSize() / 3);
            Text letter = new Text(pointX, pointY,
                String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)));
            letter.setFont(font);
            letter.setFill(this.textFill);
            letter.setRotate(degrees + this.textRotate);

            getChildren().add(letter);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, the first class relies on the user setting the font's size and the second one attempts to calculate it for the user. The original had a bug which seemed to cause the letters to be slightly offset when using specific font's and so I created the new one that you see set on the mouse-trail.

Comment: I forgot to add a note in the calculation of the poistions of the letters. The "pointX -= (font.getSize() / 3); and the pointY += (font.getSize() / 3);" compensates for the offcenter effect that would take place had you created a circle of the same size and placed it in the pane. What I'm saying is that if you did add a circle to the pane the circular text would be offset up and to the right of the circle slightly...this would place the strokeline roughly running through the center of the text.

Answer (score 5):

from the book Clean Code

> Long lists of imports are daunting to the reader. We don’t want to
>   clutter up the tops of our modules with 80 lines of imports.

I find this to be lot of imports too. But It's still somewhat OK,

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
```

Use wildcards `*` to reduce number of imports If you think imports are cluttering the top of the class.

```
@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
```

This falls under too much information category.

```
/**
 * Created by John on 7/19/2014.
 */
```

Use the `@author` java-doc annotation to specify the author.

You do not need to specify the date of creation use Revision control instead.
Next thing you know is you will be writing a log up there.